# Android Creating a MediaController Object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer

So I have a activity page with a button on it. If you click the button it takes you to a new activity page where it will play an audio file that inside `/res/raw`. This plays perfectly fine no problem.

My problem is I am unable to attach a mediacontroller object to the mediaplayer and therefore I can't play/pause/stop/rewind the audio file. So my code for the activity page that plays the media file looks something like this:

```
public class MediaActivity extends Activity {
private MediaController a;
private MediaPlayer b;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);
a = (MediaController) findViewById(R.id.mediaController1);

b = MediaPlayer.create(MediaActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
b.start();
}
```

I'm missing a few extra things like the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function, but that's not relevant here. The problem is when I transition to this activity, the sound plays but I don't see the mediacontroller. I've set the controller to visible, I've tried several things like calling the `.show()` function but still nothing. I ran across a couple of code snippets but the code is too long for my purposes, I just need to attach the controller to the player.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/-SaK9wdyz-g

Comment: i have a example that uses service and custom controller Are you looking for the same??